# How Do I Stack Javascript/ D3 bars on top of each

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

I am writing a bar graph for data that shows multiple attack tactic with other info. The tactics show up on the X axis, and they are sorted. I want it to be when there is multiple of the same tactic that they stack on top of each other. All of the other examples for stacked bar graphs use .stack, which I am pretty sure doesn't really work for this case.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>



<script>


// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 70, left: 60},
    width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    barheight = 60;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Parse the Data
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BaileyHCUDenver/KPCUDTEST/main/test-data-short.csv", function(data) {

// X axis
var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([ 0, width ])
  .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.tactic; }))
  .padding(0.2);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
  .selectAll("text")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-10,0)rotate(-)")
    .style("text-anchor", "end");

// Add Y axis //Not needed to show the Y axis because their is no need for it 
//var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  //.domain([0, 20])
  //.range([ height, 0]);
//svg.append("g")
  //.call(d3.axisLeft(y));

// Bars
svg.selectAll("mybar")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.tactic); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { 
        return height - barheight;
        })
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", function(d) { return barheight; })
    .attr("fill", "#FFFFFF") //Fill in with white
    .attr("stroke", "black") // Black outline color
    .attr("stroke-width", ); // Outline width (adjust as needed)


svg.selectAll("mytext")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .text(function (d) { return d.title; }) // Use the 'value' field from your data
      .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.tactic) + x.bandwidth() / 2; }) // Center the text
      .attr("y", function (d) { return height - barheight + 10; }) // Adjust the vertical position
      .style("text-anchor", "middle") // Center-align the text
      .style("font-size", "9px") // Set font size
      .style("fill", "black"); // Set text color

svg.selectAll("mytext")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .text(function (d) { return d.tactic; }) // Use the 'value' field from your data
      .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.tactic) + x.bandwidth() / 2; }) // Center the text
      .attr("y", function (d) { return height - barheight + 20; }) // Adjust the vertical position
      .style("text-anchor", "middle") // Center-align the text
      .style("font-size", "9px") // Set font size
      .style("fill", "black"); // Set text color
})

</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated, as I am not sure how to make it so the boxes stack on top of each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tacticCount` to save the number of tactics.

Put the bar(`rect`) and text in `<g>`, change `<g>`'s translateY basic on `taticCount`.

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {
    top: 30,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 70,
    left: 60
  },
  width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
barheight = 60;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Parse the Data
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BaileyHCUDenver/KPCUDTEST/main/test-data-short.csv", function(data) {
  // X axis
  var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([0, width])
    .domain(data.map(function(d) {
      return d.tactic;
    }))
    .padding(0.2);
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
    .selectAll("text")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-10,0)rotate(-)")
    .style("text-anchor", "end");

  // Add Y axis //Not needed to show the Y axis because their is no need for it 
  //var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  //.domain([0, 20])
  //.range([ height, 0]);
  //svg.append("g")
  //.call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  // Bars
  let tacticCount = {}
  const barItemContainers = svg.selectAll("mybar")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', (d) => {
      tacticCount[d.tactic] = (tacticCount[d.tactic] || 0) + 1
      return `translate(${x(d.tactic)},${height - barheight * tacticCount[d.tactic]})`
    });
  barItemContainers.append("rect")
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", barheight)
    .attr("fill", "#FFFFFF") //Fill in with white
    .attr("stroke", "black") // Black outline color
    .attr("stroke-width", ); // Outline width (adjust as needed)
  barItemContainers.append("text")
    .text(d => d.title) // Use the 'value' field from your data
    .attr("x", x.bandwidth() / 2) // Center the text
    .attr("y", 10) // Adjust the vertical position
    .style("text-anchor", "middle") // Center-align the text
    .style("font-size", "9px") // Set font size
    .style("fill", "black"); // Set text color
  barItemContainers.append("text")
    .text(d => d.tactic) // Use the 'value' field from your data
    .attr("x", x.bandwidth() / 2) // Center the text
    .attr("y", 20) // Adjust the vertical position
    .style("text-anchor", "middle") // Center-align the text
    .style("font-size", "9px") // Set font size
    .style("fill", "black"); // Set text color

})
```

```html
<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
```